# Java iterate List<? extends Flux>

Tags: java, iterator, spring-webflux, flux

My method gets Flux.
How do I iterate over Flux? 
I would like to go over its objects and do operation on every Child.

```
public void write(List<? extends Flux<Child>> childFlux) throws Exception {

    childFlux.stream()
            .map(children -> children.collectList())
            .forEach(child -> run(child); //not compile

} 

 public void run(Child child) {
      //TO DO
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an anti-pattern. However there are some basic mistakes.

1. `map(children -> children.collectList())` will return a `Mono<List<Child>>`
2. `forEach(child -> run(child);` you forgot one closing bracket and should be  `forEach(child -> run(child));`.
3. But it won't compile because child will be a `Mono<List<Child>>` and not a `Child`
4. When you are using reactive programing nothing happend before subscribe

What you realy need to do is something like

```
Flux.concat(childFlux).subscribe(this::run)
```

> Concatenate all sources provided in an Iterable, forwarding elements emitted by the sources downstream.

Or

```
Flux.merge(childFlux).subscribe(this::run)
```

> Merge data from Publisher sequences contained in an array / vararg into an interleaved merged sequence. Unlike concat, sources are subscribed to eagerly.